# How to express "if substring present in string do something" when using strstr?

Tags: c, string, bioinformatics

I am trying to write a very simple program, which takes a string of characters(amino acids, or nucleic acids) and checks how many times a sub-string appears and outputs the result.

However, I don't know how to state in the while if loop to add 1 to count only if there has been a match and to brake if it reaches end of the line. Since the output of strstr is a pointer towards the position of the match, I can't figure out how to express string equivalence as a logical condition for the if().

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<string.h>

   int main(){

   int j,count; 
   char *i,dna_seq[50], desired_seq[3]="AT";  



   while(1){

     printf("\nPlease insert protein sequence:\n");
     gets(dna_seq);

     printf("\nPlease insert searched sequence:\n");
     gets(desired_seq);

     while(1){
       strstr(dna_seq,desired_seq);
         if(//**answer**//); 
         count++;
         dna_seq[j]++;
         if(i=='\0') break; 
      }   

     printf("\n\nOccurance of %s: %d times\n",desired_seq,count);
 }
```

}

Also what would you write for debugging (since I am trying to practice)?

Thank you in advance for the help, sorry if the question was not clearly posed.

Comment: `strstr()`  returns a value. Use it.

Comment: Sorry, completely new to programming. 
So it will basically be if(strstr(1)){}?

Comment: @SiaNravoha if string is `amino acid` you want to count how many times `acid` is present ? Is it correct ? Because it is quite unclear what you ask .

Comment: If the input is for example a sequence of nucleic acids such as:
ACTGATCGATTACGTATAGTATTTGCTATCATACATATATATCGATGCGTTCAT
I want the program to check how many times the substring "AT" is present and output the result.

Comment: Use a counter. In the **AT** case: if you have a match (at position `pos`), increment the counter. Plus you **know** that the next possible match (if any) will be at `pos+2` or beyond. (if there is no match, there is no next match, either ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`strstr` returns a pointer to the occurance of the string you're looking for, or `NULL` if it's not present. So you should loop until you get `NULL`, and every time you get a valid pointer, increment the counter, and start looking from right after it:

```
char* loc = NULL;
while (loc = strstr(prot_seq,desired_seq)) {
    count++;
    loc++;
}
```